# PyGObject template child not defined

Tags: python, gtk, glade, pygobject

I've created a Glade UI for my GTK project with the following specification:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <template class="Pages" parent="GtkBox">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkLabel" id="page_title">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="label" translatable="yes">Title</property>
        <attributes>
          <attribute name="weight" value="normal"/>
          <attribute name="scale" value="1.5"/>
        </attributes>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="expand">True</property>
        <property name="fill">True</property>
      </packing>
    </child>
  </template>
</interface>
```

This Glade UI is linked in another UI that's run by default when the application is first launched.

Following the API mentioned [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pygobject/merge_requests/52), I tried to reference the label `page_title` in the python implementation:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

@Gtk.Template(resource_path='/com/bscubed/App/ui/pages.ui')
class Pages(Gtk.Box):
    __gtype_name__ = 'Pages'

    page_title = Gtk.Template.Child()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print(type(self.page_title))
        self.page_title.set_text("Test")
```

However the output is always

```
<class 'gi._gtktemplate.Child'>
AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute 'set_text'
```

and I can't access any of the methods usually available to a label.

However, the template definitions work just fine in the main window implementation:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

from .pages import Pages

@Gtk.Template(resource_path='/com/bscubed/App/ui/window.ui')
class MainWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    __gtype_name__ = 'MainWindow'

    toolbar_stack = Gtk.Template.Child()
    content_stack = Gtk.Template.Child()
    start_button = Gtk.Template.Child()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.start_button.connect("clicked", self.next_page)
        print(type(self.start_button))

    def next_page(self, button):
        self.content_stack.set_visible_child_name("pages")
        self.toolbar_stack.set_visible_child_name("pages_toolbar")
```

The output of that is `<class 'gi.overrides.Gtk.Button'>`

So something very strange is going on with PyGObject. Am I doing something wrong? Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: The linked example uses `page_title = Gtk.Template.Child("page_title")`?

Comment: From what I understand, the arguments for `Gtk.Template.Child` is used if the variable name is different than the child id. I tried `page_title = Gtk.Template.Child("page_title")` as well but it made no difference.

Comment: Do we see any `Error` if the `resource_path=` is wrong? Can you verify with `Gtk.Builder..add_from_file(...`?

Comment: Changing it from `resource_path='/com/bscubed/App/ui/pages.ui'` to `resource_path='/com/bscubed/App/ui/paes.ui'` results in the error `gi.repository.GLib.Error: g-resource-error-quark: The resource at “/com/bscubed/App/ui/paes.ui” does not exist (0)`. After doing some digging, I believe the bug I'm encountering is related to [this issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pygobject/issues/341)

Comment: Yes, sounds similar, worth to check used versions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GtkTemplate.Child()` instead of `Gtk.Template.Child()`.

**EDIT**: `Gtk.Template.Child()` is only available for the latest GTK+ 3 version. You should update it to the latest version or alternatively, you can use `GtkTemplate.Child()` in the `gi_composites.py` patch file.

For more information, read the documentation on `gi_composites.py` at line 162 in `/your_project/src` directory